# Validation code issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple validation script which checks if text was entered or not in a textbox. I wrote the following code, which unfortunately does not print the alert.

```
<html>
    <head> 

    <title> Js Page </title>
    <script>
    function validateName()
    {   
        var FirstName=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;          

        if(FirstName==null || FirstName=="" )           
        {
           alert("Please insert the corect First/Lastname");            
              return false;     
        }   
    }
    </script>    
    </head>
    <body>              
        <form name = "myForm" onsubmit = "return validateName()" method="post">
            First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>            
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">    
        </form>
    </body>    
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting alert with your code.

Comment: I m also getting alert with your code , your code working fine.

Comment: thank you guys, i managed to get also the alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `id`

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstnameId">
function validateName()
{
  if(document.getElementById("firstnameId").value == ""){
    alert("Please insert the corect First/Lastname");
    return false;
  } else
    return true;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From firefox error console:

> Timestamp: 6/29/2013 5:37:41 PM Error: SyntaxError: missing } after
>   function body Source File:
>   file:///C:/Users/developer/Desktop/adad.html Line: 13

You're missing `}` in function body.

```
function validateName()
{   
    var FirstName=document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value;          

    if(FirstName==null || FirstName=="" )

    {
       alert("Please insert the corect First/Lastname");            
          return false;     
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you for help, unfortunately it was my mistake when i copied the comment here, i used the } but the code is still not running. Do you have any idea why? Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you are miising "}" at the in your jaavascript function

try to add developer tools of your browser it is advisable to use.

Comment: i managed to get the alert now. thank you guys. I think it was a browser problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would ignore the emptiness because of the space characters. You should use `trim()`.

```
var FirstName = document.forms["myForm"]["firstname"].value.trim();  
if(FirstName == ""){

}
```

is good for checking emptiness.

Comment: input can be fill space characters, i specified that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use jQuery:
(give `id="firstname"` in your textox)

`$(document).ready(function() {`
    `$('#login').click(function() {`
var username = $('#firstname').val();
if ($.trim(username).length == 0) {
   alert('Please enter User name.');
   return false;
   `e.preventDefault();`
        `}`
    `});`
`});`

Answer (score 0):

```
   this is the complete validation for email
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var space=x.indexOf(" ");
var dollar=x.indexOf("$");
var hash=x.indexOf("#");
var per=x.indexOf("%");
var or=x.indexOf("^");
var amber=x.indexOf("&");
var star=x.indexOf("*");
var plus=x.indexOf("+");
var minus=x.indexOf("-");
var coma=x.indexOf(",");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
var neg=x.indexOf("~");
var neq=x.indexOf("!");
var b1=x.indexOf(")");
var b2=x.indexOf("(");
var b3=x.indexOf(":");
var b5=x.indexOf("?");
var b6=x.indexOf(">");
var b7=x.indexOf("<");
var b8=x.indexOf("}");
var b9=x.indexOf("{");
var b10=x.indexOf("|");
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Email is mandatory");
  return false;
  }

 if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length || space>0 || dollar>0 || hash>0 || per>0 || or>0 || amber>0 || star>0 || plus>0 || minus>0 || coma>0 || neg>0 || neq>0 || b1>0 || b2>0 || b3>0 || b5>0 || b6>0 || b7>0 || b8>0 || b9>0 || b10>0)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
  }
  </script>
<form name="register" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action='http:\\www.google.com' method='get'>
<font face="Times New Roaman">Email Address*</font></td><td><input type='text' name='email' value='example@domain.com' onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'example@domain.com';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'example@domain.com') {this.value = '';}">
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```